# sqoop import works with one table, but doesn't with the other

Tags: oracle, hdfs, sqoop

I have 2 tables `VB_B2B_INN_201611_201705_7` which I import to `adhoc_mn_client_inn_201611_201705` and `EVKUZMIN_B2B_CHURN_BAN_SEGMENT` which should go to `evkuzmin_b2b_churn_ban_segment`.

The script in both cases is

```
sqoop import \
-Dmapreduce.job.queuename=adhoc \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:secret/secret@//biistst1:1521/UATR15 \
--table table_name-m 1 \
--target-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/arstel.db/directory\
--delete-target-dir \
--fields-terminated-by '\t'
```

Here I replace `table name` with oracle table name and `directory` with hdfs directory. I checked both tables in oracle, they have data in them. Still, importing from `VB_B2B_INN_201611_201705_7` works and from `EVKUZMIN_B2B_CHURN_BAN_SEGMENT` doesn't.

I don't get any error for the second table. Just

```
INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 38.2422 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
```

And an empty file in the `evkuzmin_b2b_churn_ban_segment` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know that I had to run `commit;` after inserting data in `EVKUZMIN_B2B_CHURN_BAN_SEGMENT` first. After I did everything worked.